# Devise authenticate_admin wrong redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-engines

I have an app with a `User` model and the following routes:

```
devise_for :users, path: 'account',
  path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' },
  controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

And a mountable engine mounted at "/admin" with an `AdminUser` model and the following routes:

```
devise_for :admin_users, class_name: "MyEngine::AdminUser", module: :devise,
  path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'},
  controllers: { registrations: 'my_engine/registrations' }
```

Inside the engines application controller I have `before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!` which redirects *wrongly* to the **main_app root path**, instead of the admin login (or any login) page, giving:

`Completed 401 Unauthorized`

Why is it doing this and not asking the admin_user to login?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the devise routes in the main_app routes, and changed the login/logout paths slightly:

```
devise_for :admin_users, class_name: "MyEngine::AdminUser", module: :devise,
  path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'admin/login', sign_out: 'admin/logout'},
  controllers: { registrations: 'my_engine/registrations' }
```

I still think there should be a way to do it all inside the gem, but this worked for now...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :admin_users, class_name: "MyEngine::AdminUser", module: :devise,
  path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'},
  controllers: { registrations: 'my_engine/registrations', sessions: "my_enging/sessions" }

#app/controllers/admin/sessions_controller.rb
class Admin::SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController

    protected

    #Logout Path
    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
        admin_root_path
    end

    #Login Path (if already logged in)
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        admin_root_path
    end

end
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thats not really the problem here, the problem is that i cant even get as far as signing in the resource, so those aren't being hit.

Comment: Hmmmm okay. It was worth providing the code for future reference :) Have you made any progress since you asked the question?

Comment: Just posted my "solution" :)